# How to disable/hide Command prompt in Selenium Edge Webdriver

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, microsoft-edge

I'm using Selenium.Webdriver opening an Edge window navigating to a given URL , code is written in C# Windows application and I'd like to hide the black console window popping up everytime with the program .
I'm a beginner and cannot find a solution as many were provided for chrome , the single one I found for Edge was below code which doesnt work for me (I dont know if issue is due to an outdated version or reference problem ) , please advise what I might be doing wrong what could be a solution  :

```
var chromeDriverService = EdgeDriverService.CreateChromiumService();
chromeDriverService.HideCommandPromptWindow = true;
var options = new EdgeOptions();
options.UseChromium = true;

edgeDriver = new EdgeDriver(chromeDriverService, options);
edgeDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl(@Config.SpcUrl);
```

My program is currently as below :

```
namespace Testprogram
{
    public class Entrypoint 
    {
        
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            string CustomURL = "URL";   

            var driverservice = EdgeDriverService.CreateChromiumService(); //Edgedriver does not contain a definition for CreateChromiumService error 
             driverservice.HideCommandPromptWindow = true;

            EdgeOptions options = new EdgeOptions();          
            options.AddArgument("--start-maximized");
            options.UseChromium = true;  // EdgeOptions does not contain a definition for UseChromium and no accessible extension method UseChromium error
           
            IWebDriver Idriver = new EdgeDriver(driverservice,options);

            Idriver.Navigate().GoToUrl(CustomURL);
           //Other commands will go here 
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
            Idriver.Quit();   
}
}
}
```

With multiple trials the references used added up :

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;
using System.Runtime.Versioning;
using System.Threading;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Edge;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chromium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.DevTools;
using OpenQA.Selenium.IE;
```

Comment: May I know if you have got any chance to check my answer?

Comment: Hi , Yes your advise have been checked ,HideCommandPrompWindow was already turned true ,but after figuring out driverpath it was  tested with it also , unfortunately the Black commandpromptwindow still shows up , it will go tab down but I'd like to completely hide it  . Any more suggestions please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just define the service using CreateDefaultService(driverpath, and set the `HideCommandPromptWindow` attribute. Some code like this:

```
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Edge;

string driverpath = @"E:\EdgeDriver\118.0.2088.69";
var service = EdgeDriverService.CreateDefaultService(driverpath);
service.HideCommandPromptWindow = true;
EdgeOptions options = new EdgeOptions();
options.AddArgument("--start-maximized");

WebDriver driver = new EdgeDriver(service, options);
driver.Url = "https://www.yoursite.com";
```

Comment: After a while trying to figure out what I might be doing wrong , started testing on publish options as well , switched on "Configuration : Release "  and the final version it puts out works perfectly . Turns out the code in both case was fine :  `service.HideCommandPromptWindow = true; `

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this below code logic 

EdgeOptions options = new EdgeOptions();
options.addArguments("--start-maxmized");
Map<String, Object> prefs = new LinkedHashMap<>();
prefs.put("user_experience_metrics.personalization_data_consent_enabled", 
Boolean.valueOf(true));
options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);
driver = new EdgeDriver(options);
```